# How to import full database into Linux and check progress of import?

Tags: linux, database, oracle, import, oracle11g

I have Dump file 460GB export from Windows 10 with "EXP" command and database version 11.2.0.1.0.

I installed oracle Linux 6.9 on IBM SYSTEM x3650 M3 and Database same version. Can I import full database into Linux Version?. If Yes then I need to use IMP command or IMPDP command? Do, I need recreate tablespaces or datafiles?

How to check Import full database progress through SQL QUERY or Enterprise Manager?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can import it (if there's enough space, of course; 460GB is quite a lot of data).

You'd use IMP because export was done with EXP (if it was done with EXPDP, you'd use IMPDP).

Database versions are the same, so there shouldn't be any problem regarding compatibility.

As export is a "logical" operation, it doesn't care about datafiles. The database should exist. It is (from my point of view) simpler if you pre-create tablespaces so that they match the source database because import will perform CREATE (table, index, ...) operations, and these commands involve TABLESPACE values. There's no REMAP_TABLESPACE for IMP (which exists in IMPDP), so you might find yourself in trouble; therefore, my suggestion is: create all tablespaces you need.

I'm not sure whether you can see import progress.

Comment: I have log file of Export and I see Line at the end "Export terminated successfully with warnings." Is it ok or not?

Comment: It depends on what those "warnings" were. Some of them aren't important, some of them might be. Generally speaking, *it is OK* because Oracle said that it was done *successfully*.